# Search the 3 columns of names accurately

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE CONCAT(nameF, ' ', nameM, ' ', nameF) like %Johny English%;
```

Sample table:

```
nameF    nameM   nameL
-------+-------+------
Johny    Deep     English
```

I Want to get the result of data row above. But when I run the query, it doesnt match.
I know I have missing piece of codes to be accurate in matching data. Also I want to satisfy the users' even they input like "English John" or "John Dee".

Please me help to solve this.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of concatenating the three name fields and then trying to do a comparison.  Instead, I recommend just checking the name fields individually:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE nameF = 'Johny' AND nameL = 'English';
```

With regard to the input format, just solicit the three names separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM people
 WHERE (nameF like '%Johny%' or nameM like '%Johny%' or nameL like '%Johny%') 
 and where (nameF like '%English%' or nameM like '%English%' or nameL like '%English%') ;
```